# How to access model data in Ember controller

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, ember-data

I'm mainly new in Ember.
I want to access model data in my controller.
I'm using Ember.RSVP.hash to load multiple of models in my route.

**my route**

```
 model(params) {
   this.set('id', params.userID);
   return Ember.RSVP.hash({
     dashboards: this.store.findAll('dashboard', params)
      .then((dashboards) => dashboards.toArray()),
     user: this.store.find('user', params.userID)
    })
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.setProperties(model);
  },
```

**user model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  userID: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  picture: DS.attr('string'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  permissions: DS.attr(),
  created: DS.attr('utc'),
  password: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Then I'm trying to access one of the user model parameters. In **my controller** I created init function and I tried to access user model parameter. What I wrote:

```
  init() {
    console.log(this.get('user.name'));
  },
```

After that I got *undefined*.
What is the proper way of doing that?

Comment: try using a method in route => afterModel( model is the first arg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access it `init` method. You can access it in a template using {{model.user}}.

- `findAll` - you don't need to pass `params` argument you got it from model hook.
- `find` is deperecated, use query or queryRecord
- then should return the value like `(dashboards) => return dashboards.toArray()`
- You dont need to override setupController since by default it will set model hook return values in controller.
- Just ensure data is loaded in store by using Ember inspector.

Prepared [twiddle for basic demonstration](https://ember-twiddle.com/9ebef46ea66fdd3ecd43f4fc896059d2?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! What I want to do is access to model data in my controller, like variable which will have one of the model parameter.

Comment: You can access it like what you are doing `this.get('user.name')`. but not in init method. Have a look this twiddle basic demonstration https://ember-twiddle.com/9ebef46ea66fdd3ecd43f4fc896059d2?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C

Answer (score 4):

Use `this.get('model')` on your controller to access your model data as a whole. You can also use `Ember.get(this, 'model.user.name');`. You can use something like these: look at [the actions](https://ember-twiddle.com/dbc6c92604d8dd41e4ddb9c0d0763280?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

But `init` is an eager hook! `model` property has not been set yet at `init` hook!